# how we can copy custom address fields into standard address fields by onclick of button in salesforce in Account object

Tags: button, salesforce

how to create button to copy custom address fields into standard address fields by onclick of button in salesforce in Account object

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Controller Extension for Accounts with a method that will set the required account fields.

Then put a command button on a visual force page where the standardController is Account and the extensions include your class. The action for this command button can invoke your method to copy the fields.

A slight variation of this is to use a custom command button on Account to redirect the user to the above visualforce page and then fire the method in the apex:page action.

See [Building a Controller Extension](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_extension.htm).